# Populate an SQLiteDatabase in Android with static data

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I have a database with multiple tables. One of these tables (sport) is where i have to put a static list of object, each one with an _id, name, logo and an int. The _id will be used by other tables to do some queries (eg. select from "table X" where sport_id = _id), so it shouldn't change overtime (is there a way to update all the reference to this _id if it will change?).
Where should i put the code (i think it will be a simple list of db.insertSport()) to make it add this row only one time (and check if the row number grow, to add the new ones)?
There won't be much row, 50 at the best.

Comment: "(is there a way to update all the reference to this _id if it will change?)" Don't change the ID. That's a bad database practice to have the unique ID change.

Comment: That was in the case that, for some reasons (unknown to me) the _ids get changed. How can i automatically change the reference to this table in other tables? (this is a sqlite noob's question)

Comment: Looking at the answer below, Barak's answer is good. You won't really be able to automatically change the reference, so in order for you to not worry about the ID changing in the first place, create a Unique Index on the table's column of Name. Then, with Barak's suggestion, use the insert ignore feature db.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX DIFFERENT ON sports(name)"); Something like that, I don't have a SQLite or Android app to test it on right now though so you may need to tweak it a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would make a method in the dbHelper to insert that data, then call that method immediately upon app start.  I'm making a couple of assumptions here... first that you are shipping this static info with the app and when you want to add more info you will be shipping a new version.

You could store the data as a text file in your assets folder and then read the file in execute a batch insert in the method.

If you set it up right (use `insertWithOnConflict` and the `CONFLICT_IGNORE` flag in the method) it will only add the new rows (if any) each time so you can run it every time the app starts and not worry about duplicate data or crashes for constraint violations.

If you only want it to run the once and then again when there is additional info, put a version number in the text file and check that against the previous one (which you can store in SharedPreferences).

**EDIT**

Example of using insertWithOnConflict:

```
public long createItem(String yourdata) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(YOUR_COLUMN, yourdata);
    return mDb.insertWithOnConflict(YOUR_TABLE, null, initialValues,
            SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
}
```

You can read up on the SQLiteDatabase class (which has the constants and methods) [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: insertWithOnConflict seems the best solution.
I don't know where to put it. In the first activity of the app? Or MAYBE in the onCreate() of the database?

Comment: You should use it in a method in your dbHelper class.  I've edited my answer to give you a push in the right direction.

Comment: Ok sorry, i already got to that part, i don't understand when to call createItem(). Inside the SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() is good?

Comment: I would put it inside the method you create to read the file, which I would put in the onCreate of your main activity so it goes as soon as the app launches.  Just my opinion.

Comment: public long insertSport(String name, String logo, int num){ 
  ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
  cv.put(SportMetaData.KEY_SONAME, name);
  cv.put(SportMetaData.KEY_SOLOGO, logo);
  cv.put(SportMetaData.KEY_SONUM, num);

  return mDb.insertWithOnConflict(SportMetaData.DATABASE_TABLE_SPORT, null, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
 }
That's my method, it does add the sports, but they are repeated (2 times opened the app, 2 cloned rows-except for the _id).

Comment: Oh.. you need to add some constraints.  (Maybe set team name UNIQUE?) Some way to uniquely identify each row, whether it's a single column or combination of columns.  Set that, then it will not do the insert if it detects the same data.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm bothering you, but i sincerely have no idea how to add constraints and with a quick search i could not find anything to understand them.
What should i do to add a constrain that identify a sport by its name and the humber of player (Name and Num columns).

Comment: Sorry, at real life work now.  I'll try and help you tomorrow if you haven't figured it by then.

Comment: What if i put the method in the onUpdate() of the database, with a drop table before and the insert, so i have a fresh table and i'm sure i got no doubles. Plus the onUpdate will not start every time i open the app. I'm I right?